# Chart JS - set start of week for x axis time series

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, time-series, chart.js

Using ChartJS 2.4, I am querying for a set of records between two dates:

```
      startDate: '2016-11-05T18:06:17.762Z'
      endDate: '2016-12-05T18:06:17.762Z'
```

Given the scale config, I want to start the week on the user's selected date range...

```
 isoWeekday: true,
 type: 'time',
 unitStepSize: 1,
 time: {
   displayFormats: {
     'week': 'MMM DD'
   },
   unit: 'week',
 },
```

This gets me a truncated graph:

[image]

So if no records are returned for the start date, `11/5`, I manually insert data at the beginning of the array with a 0 value just to ensure that beginning date the user is expecting is displayed:

```
  if (scope.chart_data.labels.indexOf('11/5') == -1) {
    scope.chart_data.labels.unshift('11/5');
    scope.chart_data.datasets[0].data.unshift(0);
  }
```

Except doing this awkardly extends the graph out by a week with no data... and doesn't start the week on `11/5`:

[image]

How can I start the chart on `11/5`, or whichever week I want, and have the `unit: week` config increment from there?

If I remove `unit: week` and use `unitStepSize: 7` to manually set the step size, it does what I want at the beginning, but for some reason mushes in the last label:

[image]

Using `min` `max` in the `time` object,

```
   max: scope.end_display, // 12/05/2016
   min: scope.start_display // 11/05/2016
```

I get:

[image]

**Why won't it start the line chart on the 11/5?**

Labels:

```
["11/05/2016", "11/06/2016", "11/07/2016", "11/08/2016", "11/09/2016", "11/13/2016", "11/15/2016", "11/16/2016", "11/17/2016", "11/20/2016", "11/27/2016", "11/28/2016", "11/29/2016", "12/01/2016", "12/04/2016"]
```

Data:

```
[0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 7, 3, 2, 26, 2, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize I'm super late on this, but maybe you should try setting the `distribution` option to `series`. See the documentation here:

> **Scale Distribution**
>
> The distribution property controls the data distribution along the
>   scale:
>
> ```
> 'linear': data are spread according to their time (distances can vary)
> 'series': data are spread at the same distance from each other
> ```

This should fix that weird formatting that you have where the spacing is all mucked up.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify axis settings to set max and min value (start-end date range probably). An example (NB! Use your own required formats):

```
time: {
  unit: 'month',
  displayFormats: {
     month: 'MM'
  },
  max: moment(data.end_date).format('MM'),
  min: monent(data.start_date).format('MM')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it causes the same issue. See above edit

Comment: You said it does not start on the 11/5 but in the screenie you provided it does? Could you try creating a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `isoWeekday: true` into `time` config

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html